# How can I get the ID of a picture that user click on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would try to have something like five star rating , but not alone , I would like it a part of a form that user have to click on it and also enter his opinion about article , how can I retrieve the ID of picture (1start,2stars,...) that clicked on after submiting form?
Also I would like to have validation on it , I mean user have to click on five star picture.
I would like to use jquery

Answer (score 3):

```
$('img').click(function() { alert($(this).attr('id')); });
```

Should do the trick for you. [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) returns an attribute from an element.

EDIT: As per OP request:

#### HTML:

```
<input type="image" value="1" name="vote" src="star.gif" />
<input type="image" value="2" name="vote" src="star.gif" />
<input type="image" value="3" name="vote" src="star.gif" />
<input type="image" value="4" name="vote" src="star.gif" />
<input type="image" value="5" name="vote" src="star.gif" />
```

#### jQuery:

```
$('input[type="image"][name="vote"]').click(function() { alert($(this).val()); return false; });
```

This will alert the input's value, note that `<input type=image>` is a more semantic way to describe functional images, and should be used instead of `<img>` tags.

Also note that you could store the vote in a variable just as easy by using

```
storedVote = $(this).val(); //Of course goes within the click handler.
```

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RikudoSennin/x4PZm/)**

Comment: It seems I couldn't explain my issue clearly , I have a form for getting user's opinion about articles. In this form I have a fivestar voting(a group of pictures) that user can click on his/her desire ranking , I have to store this vote and send to a PHP script after submiting form (enter his/her openion and Email,...).

Answer (score 1):

Given the following element:

```
<img id="starImage1" class="starImage" src="star1.png">
```

You can do the following with jQuery:

```
$('.starImage').bind('click', function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

This binds a function to all elements with the "starImage" class that alerts the clicked element's ID attribute.

Comment: It seems I couldn't explain my issue clearly , I have a form for getting user's opinion about articles. In this form I have a fivestar voting(a group of pictures) that user can click on his/her desire ranking , I have to store this vote and send to a PHP script after submiting form (enter his/her openion and Email,...).

Comment: Your question, the only question your post, is "How can I get the ID of a picture that user click on it?" My answer clearly answers that question.